# SQL get user.emails from user_id list

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a simple SQL query but am struggling to get it right.

I have a table called trips, that has a created_at column, as well as a user_id column (among other things).

I also have users table with names and emails.

I am trying to get a list of user names and emails that have posted a trip in the last 12 months.

I have written this query so far:

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM `trips`
WHERE trips.created_at > '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Which gives me the user_id for the users that have created a trip in the last 12 months, but I don't know how to extend it so it gives me their name and emails from the user table.

Comment: Are you using  different table for user details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to query the other table as well. I assume your user table has name user. It has email name and email column

```
 SELECT user.name, user.email 
 FROM `trips`, user
 where user.id=trips.userid
 and trips.created_at > '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
```

You can use nested query as well, this query will show all the users based on the returned ids by the nested query.

```
 select * from user where id in (
  SELECT `user_id` 
  FROM `trips`
  WHERE trips.created_at > '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with a JOIN. Like this:

```
SELECT users.name ,users.email,users.`user_id` 
FROM `trips`
JOIN users
    ON user.user_id=trips.userid
WHERE trips.created_at > '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Or you could do it with an exists:

```
SELECT
    users.name ,
    users.email,
    users.`user_id`
FROM
    users
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM trips
    WHERE trips.created_at > '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
    AND user.user_id=trips.userid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS ..

```
SELECT t.user_id, u.user_id, u.user_name 
FROM trips t
JOIN users u on t.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE trips.created_at > '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select user_id, name, emails from trips where created_at>'2014-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This would be the case if the `name` was in the same table as the `created_at` field.

Comment: @parakmiakos it should be in the same class otherwise you should join tables

Comment: Read the question again. There are two different tables, so a `join` is required.